# Shortening a script using the for loop and array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jq.carousel (http://www.eafit.edu.co/banners-eafit/carousel/index.html) to showcase some images of rooms. When you click on a slide of a room, it will direct to a page with unique URL, for example http;//www...../14095/.

My first code below works but when I try to combine the "room" scripts into one using a for loop and array (see second code), it doesn't work. Does anyone know what I'm missing or need to update? Thanks ahead!

Note: the "start:" in the script basically tells what slide should appear after the load pages

Code 1: Working Fine

```
<script src="/path/to/jq.carousel.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
     // Room 1
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('14083') > -1) {
        var $carousel = $('#carousel_2').carousel({
            start: 1,
            indicator: true
        });
    }
    // Room 2
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('14094') > -1) {
        var $carousel = $('#carousel_2').carousel({
            start: 2,
            indicator: true
        });
    }
    // Room 3
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('14095') > -1) {
        var $carousel = $('#carousel_2').carousel({
            start: 3,
            indicator: true
        });
    }

  // Script for Prev and Next buttons to navigate through the carousel
  var totalSlides = $(".carousel_box").length - 4;
    $('#carousel_2_prev').on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $carousel.carousel('prev');
    });

    $('#carousel_2_next').on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $carousel.carousel('next');
    });

}());
</script>
```

Code 2: Combined "Room" Scripts

```
<script src="/path/to/jq.carousel.js"></script>
<script>
    var nodearray = ['14083', '14094', '14095'];

    (function() {
        // Section that needs to be updated
        for (var i = 0; i < nodearray.length; i++) {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf(nodearray[i]) > -1) {
                var $carousel = $('#carousel_2').carousel({
                    start: i++,
                    indicator: true
                });
            }
        }

        // Script for Prev and Next buttons to navigate through the carousel
        var totalSlides = $(".carousel_box").length - 4;
        $('#carousel_2_prev').on('click', function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $carousel.carousel('prev');
        });

        $('#carousel_2_next').on('click', function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $carousel.carousel('next');
        });

    }());
</script>
```

Comment: `start: i++,` should be `start: i + 1,`

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want the ++ on line 8 in your second code block. That will increment the counting variable `i`.

```
<script src="/path/to/jq.carousel.js"></script>
<script>
    var nodearray = ['14083', '14094', '14095'];

    (function() {
        // Section that needs to be updated
        for (var i = 0; i < nodearray.length; i++) {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf(nodearray[i]) > -1) {
                var $carousel = $('#carousel_2').carousel({
                    start: i+1,
                    indicator: true
                });
            }
        }

        // Script for Prev and Next buttons to navigate through the carousel
        var totalSlides = $(".carousel_box").length - 4;
        $('#carousel_2_prev').on('click', function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $carousel.carousel('prev');
        });

        $('#carousel_2_next').on('click', function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $carousel.carousel('next');
        });

    }());
</script>
```

Comment: shouldn't `start: i,` be `start: i+1,`